# DeRham Cohomology of punctured plane and homotopy.

Tags: homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

If I am not wrong the homotopy type of curve in the punctured plane is dictated by winding number around the puncture.

This is not the case for the doubly punctured plane (say with puncture at the points $p,q$), since the loop $γ_1$ forming loops first at $p$ then at $q$ and then at $p$ again is not homotpic at the loop $γ_2$ which forms first 2 loops  around $p$ and then one around $q$.

I have shown $H^1(\mathbb{R^2}-{p})=1$ and that $H^1(\mathbb{R^2}-{p,q})=2$. I was wondering if this result is connected to that one above and/or if there is any direct way of proving that.Maybe one way to prove this would be the DeRham Theorem but since I don't know any homology theory I can't make any use of it.

So, to make a concrete question. Is the fact about the winding number dictating the homotopies in $\mathbb{R^2}-\{p\}$ and not $\mathbb{R^2}-\{p,q\}$ related with the dimension of the dimension of $H^1(\mathbb{R^2}-{p})$ and  $H^1(\mathbb{R^2}-{p,q})$? I would like a prefer an intuitive explanation as to why or why not to a proof although that would also be very appreciated.

Comment: You want a direct way of proving what? It is not clear what you are asking, really.

Comment: are you sure you weren't wondering instead of wandering?

Comment: You are both right, I edit my question.Hope it's ok now !

Comment: $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p,q\})$ would be the free group on two generators, so you'd expect the de Rham $H^1$ to be gotten by taking the abelianization and then tensoring with $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^2$.  So if you have a path which is not contractible but does have winding number 0 around both $p$ and $q$, then presumably any 1-form should still integrate to 0 over that path.